# How to remove tags and page numbers from txt files?

Tags: html, python-3.x, text, beautifulsoup, txt

I have some txt files and I would like to **remove tags and page nums from them**. My txt file looks like this:

```
txtfile = """
    <Header>
    header contents
    </Header>
    
    The following discussion should be read in conjunction with our financial statement.
    1
    
    The interest rate charged on loans is subject to the regulation
    2
    
    of the Small Business Administration.
    
    3
    
    We are able to charge the maximum rate on certain commercial loans.
    
    <EX-2.1>
    abc
    </EX-2.1>
    
    <EX-12.1>
    def
    </EX-12.1>
    """
```

I would like to **remove tags <Header and <EX-num.num> and also its contents**. I tried to use

```
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(txtfile, "lxml").text
```

, but it only removed tags and preserve contents in the tags. Is there any way to remove both tags and its contents?

I also need to **remove the page nums**, there are 3 types of page numbers:

- pagenum + \n  (like above page 1)
- pagenum + \n  (page 2, in this case, one paragraph is divided into 2 parts by page number, and I hope to combine them into one paragraph)
- \n + pagenum + \n  (page 3)

So the text may look like finally

```
txtfile = """
    The following discussion should be read in conjunction with our financial statement.
    
    The interest rate charged on loans is subject to the regulation of the Small Business Administration.
    
    We are able to charge the maximum rate on certain commercial loans.
    """
```

Is there any way to realize that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the tags you could go with `decompose`:

```
for e in soup.find_all(text=False):
    e.decompose()
```

Removing the line breaks may use `regex`:

```
re.sub(r'(\d\n\s+)|(?<=[^\.])\n','',soup.text.strip())
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<Header>
    header contents
</Header>
    
The following discussion should be read in conjunction with our financial statement.
1
    
The interest rate charged on loans is subject to the regulation
2
    
of the Small Business Administration.
    
3
    
We are able to charge the maximum rate on certain commercial loans.
    
<EX-2.1>
    abc
</EX-2.1>
    
<EX-12.1>
    def
</EX-12.1>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.find_all(text=False):
    e.decompose()


re.sub(r'(\d\n\s+)|(?<=[^\.])\n','',soup.text.strip())
```

##### Output

```
The following discussion should be read in conjunction with our financial statement.\nThe interest rate charged on loans is subject to the regulationof the Small Business Administration.\n    We are able to charge the maximum rate on certain commercial loans.
```